# Show that $A \lor B ⊢ B \lor A$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

> Prove the following derivability claim using only our primitive rules: $A \lor B ⊢ B \lor A$

I know this can be attributed to the commutative property, but I'm not exactly sure how to prove this using only the primitive rules of sentential logic.

**Edit:** Sorry about that guys - I am working with the formal system from Teller's Primer. Also using contradiction is fine. However, primitives rules only means no derived rules so De Morgan's is out of the question.

Comment: For context,  it'd help if you listed the primitive rules you are working with.

Comment: Or at least the primitive rules that involve $\lor$.

Comment: To emphasize -- there are no such things as THE primitive rules of [classical] sentential logic. There are dozens of variant sets of rules in different styles on the market (and is worth having some understanding of why this can be so). So it is important to realise that @Alan *isn't* being pernickety.

Comment: I can guess that you have a disjunction elimination rule.  But, I'm not so sure as to whether you have one or two disjunction elimination rules.  For a proof try to assume each disjunct and see if you can derive the conclusion using disjunction introduction.  Then discharge both of those sub-proofs (or conditionals, if your system works with conditionals instead of sub-proofs) and the disjunction using disjunction elimination.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the [natural deduction rules for disjunction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/disjunction) here.

Unlike conjunction, that has only one introduction and elimination rule, the disjunction has two different intros and one elim - which is why it needs some further clarification here:

- **Elim**: $ \qquad \dfrac{\Gamma, p \vdash  r \qquad \Gamma, q \vdash r \qquad \Gamma \vdash p \lor q}{\Gamma \vdash r}$
- **Intro 0**: $\qquad \dfrac{ \Gamma \vdash p}{ \Gamma \vdash p \lor q}$
- **Intro 1**: $\qquad \dfrac{\Gamma \vdash q}{\Gamma \vdash p \lor q}$

Then:

1) $A \lor B$, Premise

$\qquad$ 2) $B$, Assumption

$\qquad$ 3) $B \lor A$, 2, $\lor$ Intro 0

4) $B \rightarrow (B \lor A)$, 2-3, $\rightarrow$ Intro

$\qquad$ 5) $A$, Assumption

$\qquad$ 6) $B \lor A$, 2, $\lor$ Intro 1

7) $A \rightarrow (B \lor A)$, 2-3, $\rightarrow$ Intro

8) $B \lor A$, 1, 4, 7, $\lor$ Elim

Comment: There's more than one way of stating the elimination rule as well. For instance, we could get rid of $\to$ and instead have the premises $\Gamma, p \vdash r$ and $\Gamma, q \vdash r$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Good point! I'm putting it this way above, since it looks better as is indepedent from $\rightarrow$ :)

Answer (score -2):

I am using rules I think are the ones assumed in most treatments of Sentence logic. 
How about:

$A  ∨ B ⊢ B  ∨ A $

Start by assuming:
1) $ A ∨ B $

2)Assume -$(B∨ A) $

Conclude $-B \land  -A$

Conclude $- A$

From  $ -A $ conclude $ -A \lor -B $

From $ -A \land -B $ conclude

-$( A ∨ B)$ , a contradiction , conclude

$(B ∨ A) $

Discharging assumptions :

---

$( A ∨ B) ⊢ (B∨A)   $

Comment: You have an undischarged assumption of $\lnot A$, so this only proves $A\lor B \vdash \lnot A\to (B\lor A)$.

Comment: OK, let me recheck. And thanks for your _actual input_ and not doing an anonymous downvote!.

Comment: @MJD: Please see my rewrite. I am looking for Tex symbols for and, I will come back and paste them.

Comment: This is terrible – unnecessary proof by contradiction!

Comment: `\land` is $\land$

Comment: I did not downvote. And, as you say, the OP has not specified the rules. It is entirely possible that a constructive proof is required.

Comment: It is never a good idea to accuse anyone of downvoting anything, because you do not and cannot know who is really responsible.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in most "primitive" rules we cannot switch from $\lor$ to $\land$ in one step, so your use of De Morgan's is not allowed.

Comment: OK, my apologies to all for the accusations.

Comment: You don't do conditional proofs in a case like this

Comment: @KyleW : According to.... And what case s it you're referring to?

Comment: According to @bbgghh. He was looking for a demonstration. Which means you have a few fixed axioms, and you use only only those axioms

Comment: @KyleW: You are forgetting/ignoring the fact that my answer was written _before_ bbgghh stated he wanted to use the condition on Teller's book. I cannot abide by conditions I am not aware of.

Comment: Sorry, didnt notice the edit times

Comment: @KyleW: No problem.